# Optimize way to append element in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

What is the optimize way to append this element to my specific `DIV Class` using JQUERY. This will generate dynamic elements. I use `.AppendTo` then display dynamically the element inside `<div class='parent-list-workorder'>`.

Here's my code so far but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var ListOfWorkOrders = [];

    $("#button").click(function(){

        //var _WOID = $('.list-workorder-id').text();

        var _WOID = $('#txtWOID').val();

        //alert(_WOID);

        $.ajax({
          url:'getWorkOrders.php',
          type:'POST',
          data:{id:_WOID},
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(output){


            for (var key in output) {

                if (output.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                    $("<div class='child-list-workorder'>

                        <div class='list-workorder'>

                            <div class='list-workorder-header'>

                                <h3 class='list-workorder-id'>" + output[key] + "</h3>

                            </div>

                            <p>" + Sample + ":" + key + "</p>

                        </div>

                    </div>").appendTo("<div class='parent-list-workorder'>");

                    //alert(output[key]);

                }
            }

            console.log(output);              

          }

        });

    });

});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're appending to a new DIV, but never adding that new DIV to the DOM.

Comment: if your're referring to this `<div class='parent-list-workorder'>`, that already exist inside my `body tag`

Comment: `$("<...>")` is not how you access an existing element, it's how you create a new element. See @Kuma's answer.

Comment: yes sir. I already updated my code. but still it doesn't work. can you make your own answer sir?

Comment: @Unknownymous2 Something you should read up on is XSS exploits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. First, you need to use a selector as an argument to `.appendTo()`, not an HTML string. Second, you need to remove or escape the newlines in the HTML string.

```
$("<div class='child-list-workorder'>\
     <div class='list-workorder'>\
       <div class='list-workorder-header'>\
         <h3 class='list-workorder-id'>" + output[key] + "</h3>\
       </div>\
       <p>" + Sample + ":" + key + "</p>\
    </div>\
 </div>").appendTo("div.parent-list-workorder");
```

Comment: I already tried your code sir but i get this error in `console.log`: [HERE!](http://s23.postimg.org/crmyqgowr/error.png)

Comment: You haven't set the variable `Sample`. Where is that supposed to come from?

Comment: last question sir., How can I click those dynamically created elements since they are not created in DOM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the code below:

```
.appendTo("<div class='parent-list-workorder'>");
```

The parameter of `appendTo()` should also be a valid selector.

you can try this instead:

```
.appendTo("div.parent-list-workorder");
```

granting that `div.parent-list-workorder` already exists.

Comment: yes .. `div.parent-list-workorder` is already exist in `body`. ANyways I tried your code but my `console.log` give me this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.` in line 25 which is the `$("<div class='child-list-workorder'>`.

Comment: @Unknownymous2 To split a string across multiple lines, you need to escape the newlines with `\`.

Comment: @Barmar can you make a post so i can trace to my code what are you trying to say?